# How to count the number of hyphens at the beginning of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a number of strings in a list, formatted as follows:

```
-Category
--Subcategory 1
--Subcategory 2
---Subcategory-Child 2A
```

I need to count the number of hyphens at the beginning of each string, so `-Category` would return 1, `--Subcategory 1` would return 2, and `---Subcategory-Child 2A` would return 3. I tried using `string.split('-').length-1` which works fine unless there is a hyphen somewhere else in the string, i.e. for `---Subcategory-Child 2A` it would return 4 instead of 3. What is the best way to count the number of hyphens at the beginning of a string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to pull out the hyphens only at the beginning of a string and count the length of the match

```js
var str = '---Subcategory-Child 2A'
var regex = /^(\-*)/g
console.log(regex.exec(str)[1].length) // 3
```

Comment: It would be safer to use `*` (zero or more) instead of `+` (one or more) to avoid an array access error in the event that the regex returns null.

Comment: aside: `regex.lastIndex` will also contain the correct answer after the .exec() fires...

Comment: Your answer is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Simply use `/^-*/.exec(str)[0].length` (no flags, parentheses or backslashes needed) to find the length.

Answer (score 0):

Replace non-hyphens with space, and then tokenize and then get the length of the first token.

```
string.replace(/[^\-]/g, ' ').split(' ')[0].length
```